# 32-bit random mapping function

Tags: random, cryptography

I'm looking for a function `f` that maps a 32-bit integer into another. The function should be bijective, and though the mapping should look approximately random, it is **not** required to be cryptographically secure. There is an important extra requirement: there should also be an easily computable function `g` that is the inverse of `f`.  It is okay for `g` to be the same as `f`, though not required.

Comment: not sure that it is right place for such question, but try xor

Comment: Even if it doesn't need to be cryptographically secure, is there anything wrong with using a 32 bit block cipher?

Comment: Something like http://www.randombit.net/bitbashing/2009/07/21/inverting_mt19937_tempering.html (which is **not** cryptographically secure of course!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I've found an ideal solution to my problem: use a linear congruential generator.  They are easily reversible and the permutation looks sufficiently random for my needs.

Answer (score 3):

There are many options given the non-cryptographic requirement, including:

- XOR (mentioned by Ilya)
- Bit rotation (f: Rotate N bits to the right, g: Rotate N bits to the left)
- Addition / subtraction (without overflow checking, so that int.MaxValue + 1 maps to int.MinValue and int.MinValue - 1 maps to int.MaxValue)
- A [block cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher) (good call @Thomas, I was focused on the easy ones :-)

Comment: There are pretty few 32 bit block-ciphers. One is Skip32

Comment: Simon and Speck block ciphers also have 32 bit variants.